# WebDriver is not being instantiated in Cucumber tests

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to instantiate a single instance of WebDriver to use throughout some tests and, in doing so, I may have over complicated.  I think I just need to instantiate a static webdriver and then re-use once for each feature file, assuming that's possible.

I'm not clear why the driver is not being instantiated.  I am trying to Debug by running from feature file in the IDE (intelliJ).  I'm expecting driver to instantiate when Super is called.

Step Defs:

```
public class FindAHolidayStepDefs extends DriverBase {

private HolidaysHomePage tcHomePage;
private SearchResultsPage searchPage;

@Before //this is the cucumber @Before
public void setup(){
    holHomePage = new HolidaysHomePage(driver);
    searchPage = new SearchResultsPage(driver);
}

@Given("^I am on the Holidays homepage$")
public void IAmOnTheHolidaysHomepage() {
    assertEquals("the wrong page title was displayed !", "Cheap Travel\u00ae : Cheap Holidays & Last Minute Package Deals", holHomePage.getTitle());
} // more step defs below...
```

PageObject:

```
public class HolidaysHomePage extends SeleniumBase {

public HolidaysHomePage(WebDriver driver) {

    super(driver);  //Expecting driver to instantiate here
    visit("");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    assertTrue("The Holidays header logo is not present",
            isDisplayed(headerLogo));
}

//code...
```

DriverBase:

```
public class DriverBase implements Config {

protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before //this is the Junit @Before
    public void before() throws Throwable {
        if (host.equals("localhost")) {
            switch (browser) {
                case "firefox":
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                case "chrome":
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        driver.quit();
    }

};
```

SeleniumBase (just a class with Selenium API methods abstracted out)

```
public class SeleniumBase implements Config {

public WebDriver driver;

public SeleniumBase(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public void visit(String url) {
    if (url.contains("http"))  {
        driver.get(url);
    } else {
        driver.get(baseUrl + url);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
public interface Config {

final String baseUrl = System.getProperty("baseUrl", "http://holidaystest.co.uk/");
final String browser = System.getProperty("browser", "chrome");
final String host = System.getProperty("host", "localhost");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, here are my suggestions:

1. You do not need to have a `DriverBase` class as you already created a `SeleniumBase` class
2. Move the below driver initialization code to setup() method in `FindAHolidayStepDefs`
3. `FindAHolidayStepDefs` should extend SeleniumBase

   `if (host.equals("localhost")) {
   switch (browser) {
         case "firefox":
                   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                   break;
               case "chrome":
                   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                           System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
                   driver = new ChromeDriver();
                   break;
           }
       }`

Comment: thanks for the comments,  1. DriverBase is for driver management, SeleniumBase is abstraction of selenium functions: both have their purpose and I don't see why I should change this  2. I don't want driver management code in my step defs - I want driver instantiation at the Page Object level